# Error al ejecutar Applet

Tags: java

*EDITO*

El problema no era nada con el navegador, ni obsoleto ni nada. Era que tenia una imagen como logo del programa, el cual aparecia en un panel, y eran problemas de permisos. Como la imagen aparecia en el primer panel, este no terminaba de cargar y por eso se quedaba en gris.

*FIN DEL EDIT*

Buenas. Estoy intentando ejecutar una aplicación que he hecho en java desde el navegador como `applet` y no puedo. Si intento ejecutarla, parece que la ejecuta, pero se queda en gris, como si no cargara los componentes, solo el applet en si vació.

La cuestión es que si lo ejecuto desde el `appletviewer` de `Netbeans` me va perfecto y no me da ningún problema.

He intentado de todo, desde poner el `initComponents()` del `applet` en el método `init()`, en el `start()`, en ambos, y no hay manera.

Sin embargo, si creo un proyecto nuevo, creo un `applet form`, le añado dos botones por ejemplo, si que va bien en el navegador...¿Alguien podría echarme un cable por favor?

Incluyo el inicio del código por si hay algún defecto que se me ha pasado:

```
public class Vista extends java.applet.Applet{  

/**
 * Initializes the applet Vista.
 */
@Override
public void init() {
    initComponents();

}

@Override
public void start(){
    controladorEmpresa=new ControladorEmpresa(this);
    controladorComercial=new ControladorComercial(this);
    iniciarModels();
    activarPanelPrincipal();
    añadirMenu();
    actionListeners();
}
```

Comment: En que navegador ocurre esto, recuerda que ya no deberiamos programar applets, ya que algunos navegadores [terminaron el soporte para NPAPI](https://java.com/en/download/faq/chrome.xml)

Comment: Ya, si por mi fuera pasaria de los applets... Pero es por una tarea del segundo año de daw.. Lo estoy intentando ejecutar en Firefox 45.4.0

Comment: Deejo otro enlace solo a modo de informar http://eleconomista.com.mx/tecnociencia/2016/01/28/adios-fastidioso-plugin-java

Comment: Entonces creo es este enlace te debe de ayudar https://support.mozilla.org/es/kb/usar-el-plugin-de-java-para-ver-contenido-interactivo-Internet

Answer (score 0):

Los applets están obsoletos y los navegadores actuales no soportan su ejecución, si quieres probarlo puedes ejecutarlo desde un IDE de Java como NetBeans o Eclipse o también podrías descargarte un versión antigua de algún navegador que los soporte.

En esta página de oracle explica desde que versiones los navegadores no lo soportan y como podrías ejecutarlos. [Información de Oracle](https://www.java.com/es/download/help/enable_browser.xml)